# How to rework this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have database table with important columns like this:

```
name | violation
file1| major
file1| major
file1| minor
file2| minor
file2| minor
```

I want to get result like this:

```
name | minor | major etc.
file1| 1     | 2
file2| 2     | 0
```

I already accomplish that with this query:

```
select distinct component as cmp ,project_id,
(select count(severity) from issue_lines where severity = 'MINOR' AND component = cmp) as minor,
(select count(severity) from issue_lines where severity = 'MAJOR' AND component = cmp) as major,
(select count(severity) from issue_lines where severity = 'CRITICAL' AND component = cmp) as critical,
(select count(severity) from issue_lines where severity = 'INFO' AND component = cmp) as info,
(select count(severity) from issue_lines where severity = 'BLOCKER' AND component = cmp ) as blocker
from issue_lines
```

Now I want to make that into view since it will be reused a lot.
But the cheeky ActiveRecord execute() command resolves the cmp from sub queries into component, and in the end I get component==component and it returns total violation across all files, not the individual one.

I can create this view with no problem directly trough Workbench, but this isnt an option.

Is it possible to rework my query to avoid conflicts with execute() command?

Comment: you could use aliases.. or just rewrite the query to case statements and group by.. or pivot

Comment: Well that's the problem, ActiveRecord resolves the alias and breaks the query. Could you provide with example of Case usage and does it work on any DB system?

Comment: I mean table aliases.. not column.. `select distinct il1.component as cmp , il1.project_id, (select count(il2.severity) from issue_lines as il2 where il2.severity = 'MINOR' AND il2.component = il1.component)  from issue_lines as il1`

Comment: Oh that's cheeky. I will try that tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Jamie, the table aliases worked flawlessly, do you want to submit that as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using your example data above, you may be able to rewrite your query using the method below.

```
SELECT  v.name,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN v.violation = 'minor' THEN 1 END) as minor,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN v.violation = 'major' THEN 1 END) as major
FROM    violations as v
GROUP BY v.name;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cae7/9)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subquery you can use CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.violation = 'minor' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as minor,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.violation = 'major' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as major
    FROM    violations 
    GROUP BY name;
```

Hope this helps..